Using epubcheck in Docker
Is there an official Dockerfile for epubcheck?
Is there a simple way to create one that uses the latest distribution (5.2) of epubcheck?
I find it so much easier to use Docker than to install Java etc on my Mac.
Thank you,
Daniel
